# Why am I getting a HTTP 500 error?

Tags: php, mysql

I've just finished off this form and I'm trying to get it to work but the server throws a 500 error at me. I don't have access to the server logs and I've looked on here.

I've checked for smart quotes and replaced the ones I could find. I've uploaded it again and I can't work out why it's still throwing this at me.

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "database";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

    if(!$conn){
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    } ?>

<?php

    $studentID = intval($_POST['studentID']);
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname);
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($lname);

    if($studentID != "")
    {
        if(($fname != "") && ($lname != "")) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE StudentID = $studentID AND FirstName = $fname AND LastName = $lname";
        }
        else if ($fname != "") {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE StudentID = $studentID AND FirstName = $fname";
        }
        else if ($lname != "") {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE StudentID = $studentID AND LastName = $lname";
        }
        else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE StudentID = $studentID";
        }
    }
    else if($fname != "")
    {
        if($lname != ""){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE FirstName = $fname AND LastName = $lname";
        }
        else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE FirstName = $fname";
        }
    }
    else if($lname != "")
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE LastName = $lname";
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>There is no query to submit</p>";
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table><tr><th>Student ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Unit 1</th><th>Unit 2</th><th>Unit 3</th><th>Unit 4</th></tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<tr><td>" .$row["StudentID"]. "</td><td>" .$row["FirstName"]. "</td><td>" .$row["LastName"]. "</td><td>" .$row["Unit1"]. "</td><td>" .$row["Unit2"]. "</td><td>" .$row["Unit3"]. "</td><td>" .$row["Unit4"]. "</td></tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>"
    }
    else {
        echo "There are no results for your query.";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

I've checked my console and everything to see if anything will show up there but I'm drawing a blank. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe because of your query, `$sql = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE StudentID = $studentID AND FirstName = $fname AND LastName = $lname";` you are not using quotes for string values SAME FOR OTHER QUERIES, SECOND, you are mixing mysql and mysqli

Comment: Turn on error reporting / display errors, should help you instead of getting a blank page / Error 500

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: also note that u have some issues in your queries condition.

Answer (score 1):

**First** of all you need to add php `error_reporting()` this will help you to find errors and warnings, but only for development environment not for production.

**Second**, very important, you need to use quotes around string values in your SQL Statements like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE StudentID = $studentID AND FirstName = '$fname' AND LastName = '$lname'"; // same for other queries
```

**Third**, why are you mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` together? you need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function here and you are using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

**Fourth**, Your code is still open for SQL Injection, you must need to prevent with SQL Attack, you can use prepared statements for this.

**Five:** i hope this is the typo error here `echo "</table>"` missing semicolon here.

---

**Side Note:**

***Very Special point***: note that `mysql_*` is deprecated and closed in PHP 7.

Comment: I missed the mysql_ when I changed everything to mysqli_. My textbook still uses the deprecated terms. :/

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `mysqli_` with the deprecated/removed `mysql_` extension. You should use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, or even better using bind variables. And as others have told if not using bind variables you have to be careful with quoting strings when creating a query